# Variable global de laravel autentificada

Tags: laravel, variables-globales

Estoy creando un menú dinámico y necesito pasar una **query al navbar**, todo funciona "perfectamente" cuando estoy **loggeado**, pero cuando tengo que **desloggearme** o **loggearme**, me salta un error.
Eso es debido a que en el serviceprovider no tengo controlado que esa query no me la pase a la vista si el usuario no está autentificado.

El serviceprovider ya lo tengo declarado también en el config/app.php

En la **función boot()** de mi serviceprovider tengo:

```
   view::composer('incs.navbar', function($view){
            $query = DB::table('aplicacions as apl')
            ->join('subaplicacions as subapl', 'apl.id', '=', 'subapl.aplicacion_id')
            ->join('perfil_subaplicacion as psub', 'subapl.id', '=', 'psub.subaplicacion_id')
            ->select('subapl.nom as Nomsub', 'apl.nom as Nomapp', 'subapl.urlweb', 'apl.id', 'psub.subaplicacion_id')
            ->where('psub.perfil_id', '=', Auth::User()->perfil_id)->get();
            $view->with('query', $query);
        });
```

Y en mi **navbar** tengo este foreach para que me muestre la consulta:

```
   @if (Auth::guest())
   @else
    @foreach($query as $resultat)
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{$resultat->Nomapp}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
         <a href="{{route($resultat->urlweb)}}">
          {{$resultat->Nomsub}}
         </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    @endforeach
   @endif
```

He probado en mi service provider poner el siguiente **condicional**, entonces al ponerlo me muestra el error a la inversa, es decir si el usuario está **desloggeado**, no me muestra ningún error y me muestra el navbar como debe ser en cambio si me **loggeo**, me muestra un error diciendo que la variable query no existe.

**Service provider con condicional:**

```
  if(Auth::User() !== null)
    {
        view::composer('incs.navbar', function($view){
            $query = DB::table('aplicacions as apl')
            ->join('subaplicacions as subapl', 'apl.id', '=', 'subapl.aplicacion_id')
            ->join('perfil_subaplicacion as psub', 'subapl.id', '=', 'psub.subaplicacion_id')
            ->select('subapl.nom as Nomsub', 'apl.nom as Nomapp', 'subapl.urlweb', 'apl.id', 'psub.subaplicacion_id')
            ->where('psub.perfil_id', '=', Auth::User()->perfil_id)
            ->get();
            $view->with('query', $query);
        });
    }
```

Comment: No le coloques solucionado al título de tu. Pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Después de un rato encallado y de debuggar, lo he podido solucionar por mi cuenta.
Qué he hecho?

1. Copiar exactamente los mismos condicionales del serviceprovider a un controller.
   En el controller me ha funcionado todo a la perfección (lo único que devolvía el navbar como vista), entonces me di cuenta que el condicional del servieprovider no funcionaba.
2. Como en el serviceprovider no funcionaba, pensé que al ser un navbar y, éste como está heredado de una plantilla, hacer el condicional Auth dentro de la plantilla, de manera que ya funcionaba todo.

Las líneas finales de código quedan de tal manera, en el serviceprovider no tengo ningún condicional, queda como el primer bloque de código que puse en el Post.

El navbar queda exactamente igual que el segundo bloque de código que puse en el Post.

Y finalmente lo nuevo que he añadido a la plantilla:

```
@include('incs.head')
 <body>
  <div id="app">
    @if(Auth::user() !== null)
     @include('incs.navbar')
    @else
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a href="{{route ('home')}}"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    @endif
    @yield('content')
</div>

    @include('incs.scripts')
```

Dónde el condicional de Auth::user() nos permite realizar todo sin ningún problema.

**Conclusión en el serviceprovider no se puede poner ningún condicional,** *(que yo sepa)*, de manera que siempre pasaba una variable al inicio de código y por muchos condicionales que ponga en la vista siempre se ejecutaba esa variable, con lo cual siempre daba error.